# How do I SELECT data from child table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.4, how do I retrieve json object like this:

```
parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
parentToChildReference: [
    {childTableFirstProp: 'another string'},
    {childTableFirstProp: 'yet another string'}
}]
```

instead of this:

```
[{
    parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
    childTableFirstProp: 'another string',
},{
    parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
    childTableFirstProp: 'yet another string'
}]
```

Do I always have to make 2 select queries, and insert one to another by usage of aliases?
Could you just show an example: how do you `SELECT` parent table along with it's children?

**UPD 1**
this:

```
SELECT
"public"."ParentTable".*,
"public"."ChildTable".*
FROM
"public"."ParentTable"
RIGHT JOIN "public"."ChildTable"
ON "public"."ParentTable"."childReference"
```

returns this:

```
[{
        parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
        childTableFirstProp: 'another string',
    },{
        parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
        childTableFirstProp: 'yet another string'
    }]
```

**UPD 2**
Create tables statements:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."ParentTable" (
    "id" varchar(36) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "parentTableFirstProp" varchar(100) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "parentToChildReference" varchar COLLATE "default"
)

CREATE TABLE "public"."ChildTable" (
    "id" varchar(36) NOT NULL COLLATE "default"
    "childTableFirstProp" varchar(100) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
)
```

Comment: Please, show the actual queries.

Comment: I've added the query i was using in description. I don't think it's matter - just give me an example, how do you select data from child table - i will figure out the rest myself

Comment: Can you please provide the `create table` statements for both tables?

Comment: I've added it in description. Originally, tables was created with navicat GUI.

Comment: These are not the actual queries. I mean, they are SELECT *, they wont return a Json, the join is incomplete and the column names are not the ones in the create table statements. Plus, the create table statements are incorrect in syntax.

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble then they are worth it.

Comment: dreaded quoted identifiers? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: There is no difference when running query with quoted table and fields: `"public"."ParentTable"` vs `public.ParentTable`.  You have spend extra afford to handle quoted string in program code.

Comment: ok, thanks! Actually, it was written by Navicat GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new feature in PostgreSQL 9.2 but I didn't test the query:

I follow the tutorial from [here](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql).

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
select ParentTable.parentTableFirstProp, (
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(child)))
  from (
    select childTableFirstProp
    from ChildTable
    where ChildTable.id=ParentTable.parentToChildReference
  ) child

  ) as parentToChildReference
from ParentTable
) t
```

Comment: Looks simple and works fine! Thank you!
One more question. It was quite difficult to find this solution. Is this approach unconventional or it is too simple to be explained in some article?
If i will use it frequently and scale it to retrieve data from 2-4 child tables at once, will this be ok in performance terms?

Comment: @stkvtflw Since this function is new in 9.2 version, it is better to do research on the logic behind.  Some applications may be using older PostgreSQL version.  It is also a concern before choosing my answer :)

Comment: @DanSin, could you, please, take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367652/postgres-how-do-i-retrieve-data-from-child-table-with-many-to-many-relations